# UITapGestureRecognizer returns 0 for location.x value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, event-handling

I am adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my Board class which is a subclass of `UIView`. I want to get the location of the Tap event. Here is my custom init method:

```
- (void)setup
{
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self 
        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    ...
}
```

and here is my singleFingerTap method:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    CGFloat x = location.x;
    NSLog(@"testing = %f", (double)x);
}
```

and here is my output for several taps in different locations:

```
2012-10-24 22:49:53.077 TicTacToe[15561:f803] testing = 0.000000
2012-10-24 22:49:53.971 TicTacToe[15561:f803] testing = 0.000000
2012-10-24 22:49:54.671 TicTacToe[15561:f803] testing = 0.000000
```

So obviously, my singleFingerTap method is getting called, but the location keeps saying that the location is at 0 for the X coordinate. I'm an Objective-C newbie so it's probably a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I fixed it:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view self]];
    CGFloat x = location.x;
    NSLog(@"testing = %f", (double)x);
}
```

I needed to add self where I had superview